# How to fold the highest headline which I am currently in?

Tags: org-mode, code-folding, outline-mode

I often do the following sequence in my `org-mode` file:

1. Go to the root headline from current position
2. Fold the whole subtree

Is there a way to this sequence with a shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code (lightly tested) takes advantage of the fact
that `org-mode` is derived from `outline-mode`, which allows you
to use the latter's functions.  It simply jumps up headlines
until it can't go any further, and then hides the subtree.

```
(defun foldup ()
  "Hide the entire subtree from root headline at point."
  (interactive)
  (while (ignore-errors (outline-up-heading 1)))
  (hide-subtree))
```

Bind it to your key of choice if you use it frequently.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you for the explanation as well!